# How to fix 'function' object has no attribute 'create_authorization_url' when using Authlib?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm writing an API that connects to Budget Insight https://www.budget-insight.com/ to fetch financial data from end users.

Budget Insight uses Oauth2 authentication on a webview where user is asked to enter his credentials to generate a code that is then exchanged for the token.

I have installed authlib and its dependencies for my project and tried different ways to make this work

First way

```py
budgea = OAuth2Session(
    client_id="37246252",
    client_secret=os.getenv("BUDGEA_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/budgea_callback",
)
```

Second way

```py
budgea = oauth2.register(
    "budgea",
    client_id="37246252",
    client_secret=os.getenv("BUDGEA_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    access_token_url="https://ynab-fr-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/auth/token/access",
    authorize_url="https://ynab-fr-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/auth/webview/connect/select?client_id=37246252&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1:5000%2Fbudgea_callback",
    api_base_url="https://ynab-fr-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/",
    client_kwargs=None,
)
```

followed by

```py
@app.route("/budgea")
def budgea():
    authorize_url = "https://ynab-fr-sandbox.biapi.pro/2.0/auth/webview/connect/select?client_id=37246252&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1:5000%2Fbudgea_callback"
    uri, state = budgea.create_authorization_url(authorize_url)
    return uri
```

Both ways return an AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'create_authorization_url' when I visit the /budgea route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the version of Authlib you are using? Please use the latest version of Authlib.

1. Then try `create_authorization_url` with `OAuth2Session` way
2. The second way is the **Flask** client way, you should use

   ```
   return client.authorize_redirect(callback_uri)
   ```